# How to save a word document multiple times with date as filename

Tags: vba, ms-office, filenames

I have a document that I use for work which is filled in every day with details of the shift to pass on to the shift coming on. These files are saved 
01 01 2017 day 
01 01 2017 Night 
02 01 2017 day 
02 01 2017 Night and so on, and filed for future reference so they are always saved with the date as the filename.

I also have two date fields in the file itself that I want to change with the filename but this is not as important so can be avoided if its not possible.

So what I am asking is! Is there a way to save the file multiple times with the dates changing in the text fields and the file name, is this possible.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use an ISO-8601 date format "YYYYMMDD" in your file names. That way your file names will sort in alphabetical and chronological order.

Comment: In the folder they are kept they actually stay in chronological/date order.

Comment: Yes you can do this with VBA.

Comment: Do the files currently stay in chronological order, or just in alphabetical order.  (I suspect that you are using a "MM DD YYYY" format, which is fine **while every file has the same year**.)

Comment: Yes, we put them in month folders so they stay in order we have no need to keep them all together as they are scanned and filed and left in a folder on file.  @TimWilliams could you point me in the right direction to a tutorial where I can learn to do this.  I have some basic programming knowledge have never used VBA before.

Comment: I've found this useful since I don't do a lot of Word VBA: http://www.susandoreydesigns.com/software/WordVBATechniques.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with VBA.  A skeleton macro is below.  It saves the file in a directory "C:\foo" with the name in ISO-8601 format.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim DateStr, FileStr As String
  DateStr = Format$(Date, "yyyymmdd")
  FileStr = DateStr & ".docx"

  ActiveDocument.Save
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\foo\"
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=FileStr, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
End Sub
```

If (aiieeee!) you wanted to run this automatically to create a whole month's worth of files in one go, you'd wrap it in a loop, i.e.

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 30
  ; do stuff here
Next
```

The "30" could just as well be a variable, of course, calculated to be 28/29/30/31 according to the current month.

Comment: Is there anyway to loop the process 30 times or 31 so I can save it for every day of the month all in one go?